# IO exception while copying 38GB of file from Local to HDFS

Tags: hdfs

I am trying to load 38GB of file from local server to HDFS, I am getting below error while file transfer

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal filename.csv /


Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSError: java.io.IOException: Input/output error
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileInputStream.read(RawLocalFileSystem.java:161)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:149)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.readFully(FSInputChecker.java:436)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.readChunk(ChecksumFileSystem.java:252)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.readChecksumChunk(FSInputChecker.java:276)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.read1(FSInputChecker.java:228)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSInputChecker.read(FSInputChecker.java:196)
at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:84)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:52)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:112)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination$TargetFileSystem.writeStreamToFile(CommandWithDestination.java:456)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination.copyStreamToTarget(CommandWithDestination.java:382)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination.copyFileToTarget(CommandWithDestination.java:319)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination.processPath(CommandWithDestination.java:254)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination.processPath(CommandWithDestination.java:239)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processPaths(Command.java:306)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processPathArgument(Command.java:278)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination.processPathArgument(CommandWithDestination.java:234)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processArgument(Command.java:260)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processArguments(Command.java:244)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CommandWithDestination.processArguments(CommandWithDestination.java:211)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.CopyCommands$Put.processArguments(CopyCommands.java:263)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processRawArguments(Command.java:190)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.run(Command.java:154)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.run(FsShell.java:287)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.main(FsShell.java:340)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Input/output error
at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:272)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileInputStream.read(RawLocalFileSystem.java:154)
... 31 more
```

after issuing copyfromlocal command I am getting above exception.
Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue got resolved, its a disk issue,